# Function not working after reset button pressed

Tags: javascript, onclick

"Clear" button clears the arrays back to default, but the newGame function refuses to run afterwards. The newGame function works perfectly as intended before the Clear function is called. I believe the new game function is the culprit, but I have no idea what part of it might be breaking it.

A different array should be expect after newGame 
is called a second time, but I just end up with an 
empty array no matter how many times I call it.

```
let shuffledBoxes = [];
let boxes = []
let boxMax = 16;
let boxCount = 0;

const newGame = () => {
  for (let i = boxes.length; i != boxMax; i++) {
    if (boxes.length === boxMax) {
      return null;
    }
    if (boxCount != Math.floor(boxMax * 0.4)) {
      if (boxes.includes(2) === false) {
        boxes.push(2);
      }
      boxes.push(1);
      boxCount++;
    } else {
      boxes.push(0);
    }
  }
};

const randomBoxes = () => {
  for (let i = boxes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    math = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxMax);
    shuffledBoxes.push(boxes[math]);
    boxes.splice([math], 1);
    boxMax--;
  }
};

const boxesClear = () => {
  for (let i = shuffledBoxes.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    shuffledBoxes.pop();
  }
  for (let j = boxes.length - 1; j > -1; j--) {
    boxes.pop();
  }
  boxCount = 0;
};

newGame();
randomBoxes();
boxesClear();
//After this point, newGame does not like to run.
newGame();
randomBoxes();

Logging boxes and shuffledBoxes show that
newGame is working before boxClear is called.

boxes =  []
shuffledBoxes =  [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
boxCount = 6

boxes =  []
shuffledBoxes =  []
boxCount =  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `reset` `boxMax` to `16` because it becomes `0` in `randomBoxes` due to

```
boxMax--;
```

```js
let shuffledBoxes = [];
let boxes = []
let boxMax = 16;
let boxCount = 0;

const newGame = () => {
  for (let i = boxes.length; i != boxMax; i++) {
    if (boxes.length === boxMax) {
      return null;
    }
    if (boxCount != Math.floor(boxMax * 0.4)) {
      if (boxes.includes(2) === false) {
        boxes.push(2);
      }
      boxes.push(1);
      boxCount++;
    } else {
      boxes.push(0);
    }
  }
};

const randomBoxes = () => {
  for (let i = boxes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    math = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxMax);
    shuffledBoxes.push(boxes[math]);
    boxes.splice([math], 1);
    boxMax--;
  }
};

const boxesClear = () => {
  for (let i = shuffledBoxes.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    shuffledBoxes.pop();
  }
  for (let j = boxes.length - 1; j > -1; j--) {
    boxes.pop();
  }
  boxCount = 0;
  boxMax = 16
};

newGame();
randomBoxes();



boxesClear();
//After this point, newGame does not like to run.


newGame();
randomBoxes();


console.log(shuffledBoxes);
console.log(boxes);
```

You can also shorten the `boxesClear` function

```
const boxesClear = () => {
  shuffleBoxes = [];
  boxes = [];
  boxCount = 0;
};
```

You can also have a single liner.

```
const boxesClear = () => shuffleBoxes.length = boxes.length = boxCount = 0
```

Comment: I actually just checked that right after I posted this. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Gewerh I am not sure that your code does. I am pretty sure it can be very less than the original one.